# Video.js issue with CHROME and IE)

Tags: html5-video

I use video-js script on my computer and it work fine, but when I check on the server, the video don't start.  Why?

Check the link for video:[enter link description here](http://www.webplustest.com/videos.html)

Thanks

Comment: Can you please supply more details like what you have done since now?

Comment: Nothing... On my computer it's OK but in the server, I don't see the video.  I upload html file and videos.

Answer (score 0):

The video file linked returns a 404. It may not be uploaded to your server or it could be linked wrong. Does this look correct?

http://www.webplustest.com/images/realisations/video/PUB_GRANIT_EXCLUSIF.MP4

Comment: Hello, I foud the problem.  The problem is MP4 and not mp4

Comment: ah yes that could be. most non-Windows servers are case sensitive.